# Write files into ZIP archive with Zip4j

Tags: java, io, zip, zip4j

I have a 3D application, where saving and loading files happens all the time. This files are huge normally but easy to compress so i wanted to Zip them. I didn't find a method in ZipFile which would let me write files directly into it, because it costs too much to open streams all the time and write temp files.

Is it possible to write directly into a ZIP using Zip4j (or other librarys where I can edit a ZIP file after creating it)? Or can I maybe write files in another Thread without having laggs?

Comment: why don't you just use `java.util.zip` ?

Comment: because it doesn't let me edit zip files. I need to do that constantyl

Comment: this looks promising https://truezip.java.net/\